# Keep specific comments when using Polymer build

Tags: polymer, comments

We're currently implementing google remarketing and have the following snippet..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 12345;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Sadly `polymer build` says no, and the CDATA comments are removed in the build process.

Is there any way to keep the comments when building?
Cheers